# Pushdown Menu - Modified Bootstrap Template

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm by no means a coder.  But I've been OK at piecing the odd piece together.

I've ran into a little snag.  I've created this dropdown / pushdown menu for a website i'm trying to put together.

It works - to a degree! the problem ive ran into is that once you select a 2nd or 3rd etc button - it would put a new pushdown menu below the original rather than removing the original and displaying the current.

Anyone know how to amend this?  I'm sure its something fairly handy but i've been looking at it all day getting it to this point so something to help finish this mini project for the day would be greatly appriciated.

EDIT - ok so i removed my javascript to see whats going on and it turns out the bootstrap.min.js along with the jquery.js are doing all the work so that leaves me even further confused.

```
javascript is melting my head :%
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oVLYNr

Thanks!
Andrew